# ReflectionUtil getField throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, reflection, nullpointerexception

I use a class that makes my Hibernate Query through a FilterCriterionList (sort of finder) and it's always worked perfectly until now  and triggers a NullPointerException and I have absolutely no idea as to why it's triggered.

This is the method (in ReflectionUtil) that triggers the nullpointer with the following values (mind you that the other values thrown at it work perfectly and it's just these that seem to give an error):

type = interface java.util.List

fieldName = parameter

First it throws the NoSuchFieldException and on it's second run (as it's called again at field = getField(type.getSuperclass(), fieldName);) makes it throw a NullPointerException and just stop dead (all of this happens in my UnitTest, not a live environment *yet*).

```
public static Field getField(Class type, String fieldName) {
        Field field = null;
        try {
            field = type.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (!type.equals(Object.class)) {
                field = getField(type.getSuperclass(), fieldName);
            }
        }
        return field;
    }
```

Any ideas as to why this happens (or what I can do to fix it?). I can't really show off more code as it's quite complicated and it's company code.

Comment: stacktraces are useful, you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java.util.List` is an interface, therefore calling `getSuperclass()` on it results in `null`.

The correct way to apply `getField()` recursively is the following:

```
} catch (Exception e) {
    Class superclass = type.getSuperclass();
    if (superclass != null) {
        field = getField(superclass, fieldName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You called like this:

```
getField(List.class, "parameter");
```

It would have never worked as List is an interface and it doesen't have any field called parameter. For the second call, its' null because interface List doesnet have a superclass.

Answer (score 0):

From the Class.getSuperclass documentation

> Returns the Class representing the
>   superclass of the entity (class,
>   interface, primitive type or void)
>   represented by this Class. **If this
>   Class represents either the Object
>   class, an interface, a primitive type,
>   or void, then null is returned**. If
>   this object represents an array class
>   then the Class object representing the
>   Object class is returned.